# Is it possible to upgrade a cisco 2600 series router to gigabit?

Tags: cisco, ethernet

I'm new to working with networks and I have two cisco 2600 series routers (specifically 2610xm) which both have Fast Ethernet ports. I have configured these and been learning how to work with them however I am reluctant to deploy this into my network as it would be a bottleneck in my network as everything else including the switches are gigabit. I noticed that there are spaces for additional interfaces at the back of the router and was hoping it's possible to add a Gigabit Ethernet interface to it.

Is this possible or am I best off keeping these separate from my main network simply for learning purposes and upgrading to a Gigabit Ethernet router further down the line?

Comment: "_I am reluctant to deploy this into my network as it would be a bottleneck in my network as everything else including the switches are gigabit._" You should be most reluctant to use those because they are EoL.

Comment: No. They are not physically capable of those speeds. (even 100Mbps is asking a lot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cisco 2610 is not only end-of-life (in 2012) but it's also rated at just 20,000 packets/s, so there's little sense putting GE ports in it (there's only a 16-port FE module).

You seriously need to replace that router.

> Is this possible or am I best off keeping these separate from my main network simply for learning purposes and upgrading to a Gigabit Ethernet router further down the line?

Sure, you can put it in a separate lab VLAN.